# How can I mount a cocoon sitemap in the WebContent folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, war, apache-cocoon

In cocoon 2.2 I want the main sitemap that is located in the COB-INF folder to be mounted in the WebContent folder of a war file and all sub sitemaps to be relative to this sitemap. I am using eclipse as my IDE. Not sure if this should be done in the POM file or can I change some settings after I import the cocoon war file into eclipse. The documentation for cocoon does not give clear examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven war plugin allows to re-arrange resources in any way.  How Cocoon will find it is an application issue.

```
<configuration>
      <webResources>
```

You might also have to make sure that it is not served out on a web request.

Comment: Right now we are using cocoon 2.1.9 and this is the setup we are using. We are keeping the sitemap from being served up. We would like to go to cocoon 2.2 and not have to make major changes to the website. Our web site is large and the company is not going to pay for us to rewrite it.